# Jasmine common tasks

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I just read the intro doc on Jasmine website, but just can not relate those API to daily DEV jobs (I use AngularJS for clientside app development, it is like write Template, directive, and set AJAX call, the only thing I can think out is testing AJAX request, other than that, I really feel difficult to figure out how to use Jasmine for something else). Could anyone give me a common task guide/example list of Jasmine for those task, I am wondering what an entire test workflow looks like?

Comment: Does this help you at all? Make sure to read the comments. http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/07/06/pragmatic-javascript-testing-with-jasmine/

Comment: If you're doing AngularJS, you're (hopefully) using Protractor, which uses Jasmine.

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck Thanks, I will read that.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks, I read the doc from angular website, in the unit testing section, it talks about Karma and Jasmine, could you tell a little detail about what the relationship between them and protractor?

Comment: @Kuan Karma is a test runner. Jasmine is the BDD testing framework.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks, but could you tell me the relationship between these 2 and Protractor? As a very beginner, I really confused what/Which to follow.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/e2e-testing (I might have been wrong about Karma.)